# Formating the string in jsp page.

Tags: jsp

I am stuck in one condition. i am using spring with JDBC template. I am displaying an jsp page where i am sending model attribute object and then displaying the content of the respective object.

```
  String test=request.getAttribute("question").toString();  
    String str2=test.substring(0, 124); 
    String str3=test.substring(125);
```

here is what i am splinting the whole string.
now in jsp tag i want to show both str2 then br and str3 below is my jsp tag

```
<input type="text"  style="width: 700px;" readonly="true" value="<%=str2 %> " id="subjectTitle"/>
```

at this point

```
 value="<%=str2 %> "
```

I want to concatinate the str2+ str3 but between dis two i want str3 string should go next line.

please help

Comment: Did you try `str2 + "\n" + str3`?

Comment: i want some do like dis value="<%=str2 %>"+"\n"+"<%=str3 %>"

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The only HTML form element that's designed to be multi-line is [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/textarea)

input type text creates a single-line text input control.[Control types created with INPUT](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4)

Comment: yes sir ,u r right it work in textarea but i want in input type tag.

Comment: check the links in the reply. You can't.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML break tag in between your two expressions to display your answer in next row